# How to advise using probabilty

Tags: expected-value

A game of chance entails three coins. For each head that comes up, the player receives £10 and loses £8 for any tail that comes up. To play the game, one pays £15. Advise a player whether it is advisable to play the game.

Comment: is this a HW question? If so please tag with self-study.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the probability of each side of each coin is 50%, then it is not advisable to play the game. Each coin has the expected value $1=0.5\cdot 10+ 0.5\cdot(-8)$. Three coins will return $3$. Thus, the expected outcome from the game is $-12=3-15$ which is worse than not playing at all.

Comment: the expected value is `n.p` how is `2=0.5⋅10+0.5⋅(−8)` is it not equal to 1

Comment: You are right, I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach based on the total number of heads in all three throws. Assuming that the coins are fair, the probability of getting $x$ heads in three throws is

$$p(x)=\frac{\dbinom{3}{x}}{2^3},\quad x=0,1,2,3$$

Now for each $x$ form the profit function

$$g(x)=10x-8(3-x)$$

Using the above probabilities now it is straightforward to show that expected profit is $3$ pounds. If you are interested, it is [the law of the unconsious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) that permits this calculation. But from this we also have to deduct the participation cost. Since on average you will then incur a loss of 12 dollars playing this game, it is advisable that you don't.